# It says "The Teradata Server can't currently be reached over this network" when i'm trying to connect Teradata using Python

Tags: python, teradata

I have been trying to connect to teradata (on on-prem server) from linux ec2 machine programmatically using python. But program failing with an error.

Here are details i used:

## environmental variables:

```
 export ODBCINI=/opt/teradata/client/16.20/odbc_64/odbc.ini
 export ODBCINST=/opt/teradata/client/16.20/odbc_64/odbcinst.ini
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/teradata/client/16.20/odbc_64/lib
```

## odbcinst.ini

```
 [ODBC Drivers]
    Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20=Installed

    [Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20]
    Description=Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20
    Driver=/opt/teradata/client/16.20/odbc_64/lib/tdataodbc_sb64.so
    # Note: Currently, Data Direct Driver Manager does not support Connection Pooling feature.
```

## odbc.ini

```
[ODBC]
# For Data Direct to load its error messages
# Data Direct Driver Manager looks for the messages here:
# "/opt/teradata/client/16.20/locale/xx_xx/LC_MESSAGES/"
InstallDir=/opt/teradata/client/16.20/odbc_64
Trace=no
Pooling=yes

[ODBC Data Sources]
Teradata ODBC DSN=Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20

[Teradata ODBC DSN]
# This key is not necessary and is only to give a description of the data source.
Description=Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20

# Driver: The location where the ODBC driver is installed to.
Driver=/opt/teradata/client/16.20/odbc_64/lib/tdataodbc_sb64.so

# Required: These values can also be specified in the connection string.
DBCName=
UID=
PWD=

# Optional
AccountString=
CharacterSet=ASCII
DatasourceDNSEntries=
DateTimeFormat=AAA
DefaultDatabase=
DontUseHelpDatabase=0
DontUseTitles=1
EnableExtendedStmtInfo=1
EnableReadAhead=1
IgnoreODBCSearchPattern=0
LogErrorEvents=0
LoginTimeout=20
MaxRespSize=65536
MaxSingleLOBBytes=4000
MaxTotalLOBBytesPerRow=65536
MechanismName=
NoScan=0
PrintOption=N
retryOnEINTR=1
ReturnGeneratedKeys=N
SessionMode=System Default
SplOption=Y
TABLEQUALIFIER=0
TCPNoDelay=1
TdmstPortNumber=1025
UPTMode=Not set
USE2XAPPCUSTOMCATALOGMODE=0
UseDataEncryption=0
UseDateDataForTimeStampParams=0
USEINTEGRATEDSECURITY=0
UseSequentialRetrievalOnly=0
UseXViews=0
EnableUDFUpload=0
UDFUploadPath=Please enter the UDF folder path
```

**Here is Python code for connecting to Teradata:**

```
import teradata
udaExec=teradata.UdaExec(odbcLibPath="/opt/teradata/client/16.20/odbc_64/lib/libodbc.so",appName="testconnec", version="1.0",logConsole=False)
session = udaExec.connect(method="odbc", system="TeraDev",username="myusername", password="mypassword", driver="Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20");
```

**Error after execution**

```
teradata.api.DatabaseError: (439, u"[08001] [Teradata][WSock32 DLL] (439) WSA E HostUnreach: The Teradata server can't currently be reached over this network")
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: From your linux box, can you telnet to your teradata server(s)  on port 1025?

Comment: I also don't see a DSN actually defined in your odbc.ini.

Comment: This error comes from the TCP sockets layer, and usually indicates a firewall or some network-related configuration is blocking the traffic from the client to port 1025 on the database server. (You don't need a DSN since your connection string is "DSN-less" with `system=`.)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, I ran "pdestate -a" and result came "PDESTATE HARDSTOP/DOWN." meaning database services were not up and running. I typed " /etc/init.d/tpa start" and then "/etc/init.d/tgtw start" after that again "pdestate -a" and this time result was "PDESTATE RUN/STARTED."

Tldr; Start the database services before trying to connect to it via a script.